# Is there a relation between people picker and user profile service

Tags: migration, user-profile-service, people-picker

I have a question regarding the relation between people picker and user profile service.

The thing is i'm planning to move content from sp 2007 to 2010, but without SSP database, so user profiles will not be moved.

The user profile service I will configure at the end of the migration.

My question is, will the pickers be broken everywhere, and i would not be able to use it if the user profile service is not configured?

Is there maybe some article explaining that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The people picker will connect to BOTH Active Directory and the User Profile Service. Even without the User Profile Service names will resolve from AD.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to migrate content databases over to an other machine. Even if the source system contains users that are unknown in the target system. (and even if they are on a completely different Active Directory)

The people picker will always connect to the User Profile Service configured on the farm it runs on. Don't forget to set the correct site administrator in Central Administration after migrating.

We do it all the time when we are moving configured SharePoint solutions from Test to Production. 
Items might display the names of the users from the test environment. When editing these items you will have to select a valid user from the current system otherwise you can not save the item.

So, no the people picker will not be broken. You might see names that are not on your target system but you can easily change this.